# Get link text before specific div using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm doing some code in other to **scrape** a page for a specific search result, but the main problem is using regex with python.

Here is part of the website source:

```
            <div class="title_block">
            <div class="ttl-oss">  </div>
                <a href="https://url.com/search">TEXT-TO-CATCH</a>
            </div>
```

The div `ttl-oss` appears just one time in the page, so my ideia is to use regex in other to search for the unique div, and get the first link text after it like `(TEXT-TO-CATCH)`.

The problem is if I use some regex like `<div class="title_block">.*?(<a.*?>)+` I'm not able to find the div and get the text.

Any new approach in how to solve it, is welcome.

Thank you

Comment: `soup.get_text()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML is usually better handled by an HTML parser, and several are available for python. Regex in general isn't flexible enough for complicated HTML.

However, this should get the text you're looking for, assuming your page looks similar to the one you've posted as an example.

`<div class="ttl-oss">[\s\S]*?<a[^>]*href.*>(.*)<\/a>`

This regex looks for a div structured as you described in your example, looks for the first anchor tag it finds past that which has "href" in it, and then captures the first chunk of text after the closing `>`, capturing up to the closing `</a>` tag.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VsyZDP/1/)

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you!